# From a RaycastHit on the gameobject surface to a random point ont the gameobject on JellySurface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically I got a code that transforms a gameobject surface in a jelly like substance
https://heliosinteractive.com/jelly-shader-part-7/
I need my slime to have always this jelly like effect not only when hitted

It is the initial code I transformed in to something like that yet it dosent work every time.

public class JellyClickReceiver : MonoBehaviour {

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray clickRay;

Renderer modelRenderer;
float controlTime;

public Vector3[] positions;

void Start ()
{
    modelRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    InvokeRepeating("shader", 1.0f, 6f); //calls the deformation function every 6s
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    controlTime += Time.deltaTime;
    //clickRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);      
    modelRenderer.material.SetFloat("_ControlTime", controlTime);
}

void shader()
{
    controlTime = 0;

    modelRenderer.material.SetVector("_ModelOrigin", transform.position);
    modelRenderer.material.SetVector("_ImpactOrigin", positions[Random.Range(0, positions.Length)]);

    //Debug.Log(hit.point);
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing that I notice, will be that you are using positions[Random.Range(0, positions.Length)] but that should be positions.Length-1
most likely you are getting errors in your code about being out of range/not a valid index in the array.

Your positions[] (and i'm not sure what you put into it) are going to be just flat Vector3 world space values that don't move. If you are moving the jelly around, of course this won't work.

Basically, the original code gets the hit.point which is a position in world space (Vector3) of where the raycast hit the jelly based on where you clicked on the screen.

All it does is create from the vector a direction in the shader code. So those positions don't have to be very accurate, I think they can be just generally in the correct spot but they do need to be in world space relative to the jelly's current position.

My advice, (first, make it array.Length-1 in your code) keep the same code that you have and instead of using Vector3[] array use a Transform array and place some gameobjects that are children of the jelly's body. Move those gameobjects to positions around the body of the jelly, and drag all of them into your array.

```
public Transform[] positions;
modelRenderer.material.SetVector("_ImpactOrigin", positions[Random.Range(0, positions.Length-1)].position);
```

fixing positions.Length-1, and using transforms that are childs of the jelly will fix your error (which is why it randomly stops working sometimes) and allow it to move around